# How do I show a sum of 2 text box numbers in a "progressive score" text box without button to calculate

Tags: android

Looking for simple solution for adding two numbers, each from a sperate text box and are not in integer form, and displaying in a third text box adjacent to "progressive score" text box. For example, number "1" result in a text box and then a number "4" in the next text box shows a progressive total of 5.
Thankyou.

Have tried integer parseint without success.

NEED TO GET NUMBER (unformatted ie "0" FROM TV AND TV2 to TV3

```
String s9;
        s9 =tv.getText().toString();
        int n9;
        n9 = Integer.parseInt(s9);
        String s10;
        s10 = tv2.getText().toString();
        int n10;
        n10 = Integer.parseInt(s10);
```

A simple 4 and 8 makes 12 with automatic calculation (no button).
Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
String s9;
        s9 =tv.getText().toString();
        int n9;
        n9 = Integer.parseInt(s9);
        String s10;
        s10 = tv2.getText().toString();
        int n10;
        n10 = Integer.parseInt(s10);



tv.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
           if (!tv2.getText().toString().isEmpty()) 
           {
             int result= n9+n10;
             tv3.setText(result);
           }
        }
    });


tv2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
           if (!tv.getText().toString().isEmpty()) 
           {
              int result= n9+n10;
             tv3.setText(result);
           }
        }
    });
```